# Saving a Map to a local file

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to save a Map in to a local file.
I have multiple Maps nested in to each other.
I already tried using `json.Encode()` but then i get the error `JsonUnsupportedObjectError (Converting object to an encodable object failed: _LinkedHashMap len:9)`.

```
class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  Map week = new Map();
  final FachController = TextEditingController();
  final LehrerController = TextEditingController();
  Map feacher = new Map();

  List<Widget> makeList() {
    List days = ["Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr"];
    List st = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    readWeek();
    if (week.isEmpty) {
      for (var i in days) {
        week[i] = new Map();
        for (var b in st) {
          week[i][b] = {"F": "", "R": "", "L": "", "U": ""};
        }
      }
    }

    List rlist = new List<Widget>();
    rlist.add(createNoTouchTile("St."));
    for (var i in week.keys) {
      rlist.add(createNoTouchTile(i));
    }

    for (var i in st) {
      rlist.add(createNoTouchTile(i.toString() + "."));
      for (var b in week.keys) {
        rlist.add(createTouchTile(
          week[b][i]["F"],
          week[b][i]["R"],
          week[b][i]["L"],
          week[b][i]["U"],
          b,
          i,
        ));
      }
    }

    return rlist;
  }

  writeWeek() async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    var path = directory.path;
    var ffile = File("$path/week.data");
    var war = json.encode(week);
    await ffile.writeAsString(war);
  }

  readWeek() async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    var path = directory.path;
    var ffile = File("$path/week.data");
    var wekk = jsonDecode(await ffile.readAsString());
    print(wekk.runtimeType);
  }

  }
}
```

I'm trying to read and write at readWeek() and writeWeek() and the Map week gets created at makeList()

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Post your best attempt? We cannot help you with code we cannot see.

Comment: I hope its better now

Comment: What does createNoTouchTile return ?

Comment: First you need a map with string keys to be json encodable: List st = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; to List st = ["1", "2", "3", ...];

Comment: A GridTile and createTouchTile as well

Comment: Thanks that did it.

Comment: Ok @3tes , can I put it as the solution then?

Comment: yes you can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a map with string keys to be json encodable.

Replace:

```
List st = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

with:

```
List st = ["1", "2", "3", ...];
```

For reference see here:
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.1/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html